# IOS Native Captured Video is not playing on Android and vice versa

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, video, mpmediaplayercontroller

IOS captured video is not playing on Android Application and same as Android captured video is not playing on MPMediaPlayerViewController (IOS device) both have same codecs.

**IOS Side Video info:**
**Video:**
Dimensions 640x480
Codec H.264 / AVC
24 frames per seconds
**Audio:**
Codec Mpeg-4 AAc audio
Channels Stereo
Sample Rate 44100 Hz
Bitrate 64 kbps

**Android Side Video info:**
**Video:**
Dimensions 352x288
Codec H.264 / AVC
26 frames per seconds
**Audio:**
Codec Mpeg-4 AAc audio
Channels Stereo
Sample Rate 48000 Hz
Bitrate 96 kbps

Any solution?